# Android - Menu items are not shown in ActionBar to start app

Tags: android, menu, tabs, fragment

I am creating a Activity with 2 Fragments. I am implementing a different Menu Items for each Fragment. But I am having a problem. Sequence of my error:

- Tab 1 - Fragment 1 -> No buttons appear on the ActionBar the Menu
- Tab 2 - Fragment 2 -> The menu appears correctly
- Tab 1 - Fragment 1 -> The menu is displayed

Until I pass by the Fragment 2 and return to the Fragment 1 my icons of ActionBar are not shown. What can be my error? Thank you

**Fragment 1**

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_listado, container, false);

    declararObjetos();
    iniciarBaseDatos();
    sonidos();
    cargarLocalizacion();
    reiniciarListview();
    pintarElementos();

    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    Modulo.getOverflowMenu(getActivity());
    ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu((Activity) context);

    return rootView;
}

public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menuItemActualizarLista = menu.findItem(R.id.menuOpcActualizarLista);
    menuItemBuscar = menu.findItem(R.id.menuOpcBuscar);

    menuItemActualizarLista.setVisible(true);
    menuItemBuscar.setVisible(true);
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menuOpcActualizarLista:

        reiniciarListview();
        return true;

    case R.id.menuOpcBuscar:

        cargarBuscar();
        return true;

    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**MENU**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menuOpcActualizarLista"
    android:visible="false"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/menuOpcBuscar"
      android:icon="@drawable/icono_lupa"
      android:visible="false"
      android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Comment: What is this fragment? Fragment 1 or 2?

Comment: I see no menu inflation.. Where is `onCreateOptionsMenu`?

Comment: I don't use onCreateOptionsMenu because my menu worked ok until now

Comment: Also try changing `ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu((Activity) context);` to `onActivityCreated`

Comment: Can you show all code of onActivityCreated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to inflate a menu so you can show it.

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Modulo.getOverflowMenu(getActivity());
    ActivityCompat.invalidateOptionsMenu(getActivity());
}
```

Comment: I have edited my code. I show my menu. With your code, only `menuOpcBuscar` is shown to start. 3 dots not shown but Menu botton works

Comment: The other one doesn't have title or icon. What do you want to be shown?

Comment: Please properly type your menu item. You need to add a title and set `showAsAction` to `ifRoom`.

Comment: I don't want an item with text. I want an item in the menu of the 3 dots

Comment: then use `android:showAsAction="never"`. But you still need a title.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66985/discussion-between-user4152-and-pedro-oliveira).